# implementing BubbleSort in scala

Tags: scala, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement Bubble Sort in Scala.

This is my implementation:

```
object Example {

  def bubbleSort(arr:Array[Int])={
    var temp=0
    for(i<- 1 until arr.length-1 ; j<- 1 until (arr.length-1-i)){
      if(arr(j-1)>arr(j)) {
        temp=arr(j-1)
        arr(j-1)=arr(j)
        arr(j)=temp 
       }
     }
     arr
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x = bubbleSort(Array(3, 60, 35, 2, 45, 320, 5))
    println(x)
  }

}
```

The problem is that the following output is printed:

```
[I@68be2bc2
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Add `.mkString(",")` when you println. Arrays are usually not printed nice. In Java you'd say `Arrays.toString(x)`

Comment: Thanks Stefanobaghino ,It works

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is here:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x = bubbleSort(Array(3, 60, 35, 2, 45, 320, 5))
    println(x)
  }
```

you are really printing the reference of the array x not the elements of it.

to print each element of the array use

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x = bubbleSort(Array(3, 60, 35, 2, 45, 320, 5))
    x.foreach(println)
  }
```